# Can I use an iPad (Wi-Fi+Cellular) as a cellphone?

Tags: ipad

I just wanted to know whether is possible to use an iPad mini as a cell phone. I am planning to put my SIM card into the iPad mini, which is the Wi-Fi+cellular model.

Comment: Keep in mind: the iPad does not have a motor, so notifications (text messages, appointments, incoming calls) will not get your attention if you manage to pocket it, even after you figure out VoIP, etc.

Answer (score 32):

No, you can't use it as a *carrier* cellphone. But if you have enough data in your plan, you can use it as a cellphone through services such as [Google Voice](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/google-voice/id318698524) or [Skype](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/skype-for-ipad/id442012681) which can give you a phone number that you can call with and be called with over the internet. They both provide apps that will "ring" your iPad when someone calls the number.

Google Voice is free to have a phone number. Calls From the US or Canada to the US or Canada are free, and calls to or from other places are pretty cheap.

Skype charges for a phone number, but that includes some sort of fee that gives you a predetermined number of minutes.

Comment: Line2 (http://www.line2.com/home/) is another option similar to Skype/Google Voice. When I started using it I found it had better text messaging support than the alternatives, and it's unlimited calling/texting for a flat monthly rate.

Comment: If having an actual number isn't a requirement, the Facebook app just added audio messaging. That's another good option.

Comment: Note that some of these free carriers instead uses your communication as payment (that is they save it for mining).  Carefully consider how you would like to pay.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Absolutely, and these years on I would always recommend finding a paid VoIP provider (though I don't know a good one myself) -- well, honestly, a paid *anything* provider. It's much better to pay with a little bit of cash than an unquantifiable and opaque amount of sacrificed control and privacy.

Answer (score 20):

If you mean whether you can make phone calls using your SIM card, **no, you can't**:

(from http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/)

[image]

Still, you can use Skype or a [VoIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voip)-based phone app (just search the App Store for VoIP), either over WiFi or, if your SIM card has a data plan, over cellular.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with Tu GO http://www.o2.co.uk/tugo/want-it
Enjoy.

Comment: How does that work? Does it use the sim data plan, or the sim phone plan?